# Golang: Implementing a cron / executing tasks at a specific time

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks, cron, ticker

I have been looking around for examples on how to implement a function that allows you to execute tasks at a certain time in Go, but I couldn't find anything.

I implemented one myself and I am sharing it in the answers, so other people can have a reference for their own implementation.

Comment: shameless plug: perhaps you could check this out: minimalist cron go-package: github.com/roylee0704/gron

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a general implementation, which lets you set:

- interval period
- hour to tick
- minute to tick
- second to tick

**UPDATED:** (the memory leak was fixed)

```
import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

const INTERVAL_PERIOD time.Duration = 24 * time.Hour

const HOUR_TO_TICK int = 23
const MINUTE_TO_TICK int = 00
const SECOND_TO_TICK int = 03

type jobTicker struct {
    timer *time.Timer
}

func runningRoutine() {
    jobTicker := &jobTicker{}
    jobTicker.updateTimer()
    for {
        <-jobTicker.timer.C
        fmt.Println(time.Now(), "- just ticked")
        jobTicker.updateTimer()
    }
}

func (t *jobTicker) updateTimer() {
    nextTick := time.Date(time.Now().Year(), time.Now().Month(), 
    time.Now().Day(), HOUR_TO_TICK, MINUTE_TO_TICK, SECOND_TO_TICK, 0, time.Local)
    if !nextTick.After(time.Now()) {
        nextTick = nextTick.Add(INTERVAL_PERIOD)
    }
    fmt.Println(nextTick, "- next tick")
    diff := nextTick.Sub(time.Now())
    if t.timer == nil {
        t.timer = time.NewTimer(diff)
    } else {
        t.timer.Reset(diff)
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation leaks memory.

> Stop the ticker to release associated resources.

Comment: @Caleb is right, each time we create a new ticker, the old one will never be released. a better solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39295990/2791115

Comment: @Caleb, thanks! feel free to update the code on the answer, to fix the leak

Comment: isn't it got garbage collected?

Comment: This doesn't handle NTP clock adjustment well... a daily ticker fires twice sometimes.

Answer (score 30):

In case someone drops in on this question searching for a quick solution.
I found a neat library that makes it really easy to schedule jobs.

Link: https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron

The API is pretty straightforward:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron"
)

func task() {
    fmt.Println("Task is being performed.")
}

func main() {
    s := gocron.NewScheduler()
    s.Every(2).Hours().Do(task)
    <- s.Start()
}
```

Answer (score 24):

the answer provided by @Daniele B is not good enough, as @Caleb says, that implementation leaks memory, because each time we create a new ticker, the old one will never be released.

so I wrap the `time.timer`, and reset it everytime, a example here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const INTERVAL_PERIOD time.Duration = 24 * time.Hour

const HOUR_TO_TICK int = 23
const MINUTE_TO_TICK int = 21
const SECOND_TO_TICK int = 03

type jobTicker struct {
    t *time.Timer
}

func getNextTickDuration() time.Duration {
    now := time.Now()
    nextTick := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), HOUR_TO_TICK, MINUTE_TO_TICK, SECOND_TO_TICK, 0, time.Local)
    if nextTick.Before(now) {
        nextTick = nextTick.Add(INTERVAL_PERIOD)
    }
    return nextTick.Sub(time.Now())
}

func NewJobTicker() jobTicker {
    fmt.Println("new tick here")
    return jobTicker{time.NewTimer(getNextTickDuration())}
}

func (jt jobTicker) updateJobTicker() {
    fmt.Println("next tick here")
    jt.t.Reset(getNextTickDuration())
}

func main() {
    jt := NewJobTicker()
    for {
        <-jt.t.C
        fmt.Println(time.Now(), "- just ticked")
        jt.updateJobTicker()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I have created a package that actually supports crontab syntax if you are familiar with it, for example:

```
ctab := crontab.New()
ctab.AddJob("*/5 * * * *", myFunc)
ctab.AddJob("0 0 * * *", myFunc2)
```

Package link: https://github.com/mileusna/crontab

Comment: This is actually really nice! Thx for creating this package :)

Answer (score 8):

This is another general implementation without need for a third party library.

**Disclaimer: This implementation works with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). For managing timezones it has to be modified.**

Run a `func` once a day at noon.

- Period: `time.Hour * 24`
- Offset: `time.Hour * 12`

Run a `func` twice a day at 03:40 (00:00 + 03:40) and 15:40 (12:00 + 03:40).

- Period: `time.Hour * 12`
- Offset: `time.Hour * 3 + time.Minute * 40`

## Updated (2020-01-28):

Changes:

- `context.Context` can be used for cancellation, makes it testable.
- `time.Ticker` removes the need for calculating the time of the next execution.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "time"
)

// Schedule calls function `f` with a period `p` offsetted by `o`.
func Schedule(ctx context.Context, p time.Duration, o time.Duration, f func(time.Time)) {
    // Position the first execution
    first := time.Now().Truncate(p).Add(o)
    if first.Before(time.Now()) {
        first = first.Add(p)
    }
    firstC := time.After(first.Sub(time.Now()))

    // Receiving from a nil channel blocks forever
    t := &time.Ticker{C: nil}

    for {
        select {
        case v := <-firstC:
            // The ticker has to be started before f as it can take some time to finish
            t = time.NewTicker(p)
            f(v)
        case v := <-t.C:
            f(v)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            t.Stop()
            return
        }
    }

}
```

## Original:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"
)

// Repeat calls function `f` with a period `d` offsetted by `o`.
func Repeat(d time.Duration, o time.Duration, f func(time.Time)) {
    next := time.Now().Truncate(d).Add(o)
    if next.Before(time.Now()) {
        next = next.Add(d)
    }

    t := time.NewTimer(next.Sub(time.Now()))

    for {
        v := <-t.C
        next = next.Add(d)
        t.Reset(next.Sub(time.Now()))
        f(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/ehsaniara/gointerlock. It's also supported in distributed systems and has a builtin distributer lock (Redis)

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ehsaniara/gointerlock"
    "log"
    "time"
)

var job = gointerlock.GoInterval{
    Interval: 2 * time.Second,
    Arg:      myJob,
}

err := job.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error: %s", err)
}

func myJob() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now(), " - called")
}
```