# How to run the cron job according to the particular time zone with intervals

Tags: go, cron, timezone, intervals

I'm making the cron job for monitoring the data. But before this while I'm reading the documentation of the cron in [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2) in this they say we will run the cron according to the particular `time_zone` and intervals. Now I'm using only intervals in the cron job. But, Now I want to use `time_zone` too in the cron job means to say cron job will run according to the particular `time_zone` on the particular time interval. Suppose I'm in USA and there are different `time_zone` and I'm in `Chicago` and I want my cron will run every after 2 hours according to the `time_zone` of each country. Can we use `time_zone` and `interval` together? if Yes, Then please tell how can we use it in below function:-

`cron.go`

```
package cron

import (
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2"
)
func RunCron() {
    c := cron.New()

    c.AddFunc("Here I want the time_zone and intervals together", AutomaticChargedCron)
    c.Start()
}
```

I No, Can you tell me that how this will posible to make a cron like that or make a other cron for monitoring the time_zone.

Comment: To be fair I have created a cron which runs every 2AM in night according to US timings. But If you are creating a cron which runs every 2 hours, I do'nt think you need to add a timezone. Since the cron is not running once or twice in a day. It is running every 2 hours.

Comment: @Himanshu not every 2 hours. okay, I'm explain you one thing is that suppose the time in `chicago is 05:00` AM and in new york is `06:00AM`. and there is a booking for chicago start at `06:00 AM` and end at  `07:00 AM` and There is a booking for New york start at `06:30 AM` and end at `07:30 AM` and the admin set the cron time of 2 hours  then for chicago it will run at `09:00 AM` and for New York it will run `09:30 AM` Now you got what I want?

Comment: @Himanshu, two hours on a wall clock aren't always 120 minutes on a stopwatch: https://play.golang.org/p/q4eBklpjUnn. Selecting the correct timezone for the desired behavior is important.

Comment: @misha, what's unclear about the example in the [usage](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2#hdr-Usage)?

Comment: Hey Misha, I think you want to do some delayed processing of some kind, I would suggest you take a look at Publish-Subscribe model, as cron based processes do add a bit of complexity and doesn't scale too well. For the cron although, you can try using tickers, example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549199/golang-implementing-a-cron-executing-tasks-at-a-specific-time , golang also provides native tickers, so you can implement your own version and run multiple tickers for different UTC offsets. Here: https://gobyexample.com/tickers