# Run cron on weekdays only

Tags: go, time, cron

Currently have this cron code below which is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549199/golang-implementing-a-cron-executing-tasks-at-a-specific-time) Trying to make this can be so it can run the job only on weekdays only.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const INTERVAL_PERIOD time.Duration = 24 * time.Hour

const HOUR_TO_TICK int = 23
const MINUTE_TO_TICK int = 21
const SECOND_TO_TICK int = 03

type jobTicker struct {
    t *time.Timer
}

func getNextTickDuration() time.Duration {
    now := time.Now()
    nextTick := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), HOUR_TO_TICK, MINUTE_TO_TICK, SECOND_TO_TICK, 0, time.Local)
    if nextTick.Before(now) {
        nextTick = nextTick.Add(INTERVAL_PERIOD)
    }
    return nextTick.Sub(time.Now())
}

func NewJobTicker() jobTicker {
    fmt.Println("new tick here")
    return jobTicker{time.NewTimer(getNextTickDuration())}
}

func (jt jobTicker) updateJobTicker() {
    fmt.Println("next tick here")
    jt.t.Reset(getNextTickDuration())
}

func main() {
    jt := NewJobTicker()
    for {
        <-jt.t.C
        fmt.Println(time.Now(), "- just ticked")
        jt.updateJobTicker()
    }
}
```

How can I make this only run on the weekdays only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for day of the week inside your **getNextTickDuration()** function. It may look like this

```
func getNextTickDuration() time.Duration {
    now := time.Now()
    nextTick := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), HOUR_TO_TICK, MINUTE_TO_TICK, SECOND_TO_TICK, 0, time.Local)
    for nextTick.Before(now) || nextTick.Weekday() == time.Saturday || nextTick.Weekday() == time.Sunday {
        nextTick = nextTick.Add(INTERVAL_PERIOD)
    }
    return nextTick.Sub(time.Now())
}
```